# What is the pythonic way to calculate dot product?

Tags: python, dot-product

I have two lists, one is named as A, another is named as B. Each element in A is a triple, and each element in B is just an number. I would like to calculate the result defined as :

```
result = A[0][0] * B[0] + A[1][0] * B[1] + ... + A[n-1][0] * B[n-1]
```

I know the logic is easy but how to write in pythonic way?

Thanks!

Comment: The way `A` is structured, it's a 2D list/matrix.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
import numpy
result = numpy.dot( numpy.array(A)[:,0], B)
```

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/

If you want to do it without numpy, try

```
sum( [a[i][0]*b[i] for i in range(len(b))] )
```

Answer (score 80):

Python 3.5 has an explicit operator `@` for the dot product, 
so you can write

```
a = A @ B
```

instead of

```
a = numpy.dot(A,B)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443562/is-there-really-an-operator-in-python-to-calculate-dot-product for a caveat

Comment: actually, the `@` operator is of Numpy rather than of Python

Comment: @WalterTross the `@` is of Python, though it doesn't use it currently. Numpy implements it in its arrays.

Comment: that's why I wrote "rather than" instead of ", not"  ;-)

Comment: The `@` operator was specifically meant for matrix multiplication, so numpy is not making anything up: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/ (it's just that base Python does not have matrices)

Comment: This post makes it sound like `[1,2,3] @ [2,1,1]` should work, but it does not.

Comment: `@` is for matrix multiplication not for dot product.

Comment: @run_the_race Yes it does, but with numpy arrays: `np.array([1,2,3]) @ np.array([2,1,1])`

Comment: @thyu It seems that NumPy (really, PEP-0465) has decided that `@` applied to two `numpy.ndarray` (as opposed to two `numpy.matrix`) shall be interpreted as the dot product of the `numpy.ndarray`. Works for me. After all "a dot b" is the matrix multiplication "a x transpose(b)" if a and b are "column vectors" interpreted as matrices. See in particular [Semantics of `@`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/#semantics) in PEP-0465.

Answer (score 32):

My favorite Pythonic dot product is:

```
sum([i*j for (i, j) in zip(list1, list2)])
```

So for your case we could do:

```
sum([i*j for (i, j) in zip([K[0] for K in A], B)])
```

Comment: builds the whole list before summing

Answer (score 24):

```
from operator import mul

sum(map(mul, A, B))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the operator and the itertools modules:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import imap

sum(imap(mul, A, B))
```

Comment: In Python 3.0 and above, map behaves like imap: https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

Answer (score 3):

Using [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), a third-party library that implements the `dotproduct` [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
import more_itertools as mit


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [7, 8, 9]

mit.dotproduct(a, b)
# 50
```

Answer (score 3):

People are re-assigning the @ operator as the dot product operator.  Here's my code using vanilla python's zip which returns a tuple.  Then uses list comprehension instead of map.

```
def dot_product(a_vector,b_vector):
    #a1 x b1 + a2 * b2..an*bn return scalar
    return sum([an*bn for an,bn in zip(a_vector,b_vector)])

X = [2,3,5,7,11]
Y = [13,17,19,23,29]
print(dot_product(X,Y)) #652

a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
print(dot_product(a,b)) #prints 32= 1*4 + 2*5 + 3*6 = 
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [7, 8, 9]
print(dot_product(a,b)) #prints 50
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> X = [2,3,5,7,11]
>>> Y = [13,17,19,23,29]
>>> dot = lambda X, Y: sum(map(lambda x, y: x * y, X, Y))
>>> dot(X, Y)
652
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most Pythonic way for this kind of thing is to use [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.12+ you can use [`math.sumprod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.sumprod).

Given your situation

```py
A = [
    (1, 11, 111),
    (2, 22, 222),
]
B = [10, 100]

first_column = (row[0] for row in A)
```

you can compute `A[0][0] * B[0] + A[1][0] * B[1]` with

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.sumprod(first_column, B)
210
```

---

In older versions the most pythonic way is probably to use `sum` with a generator (i.e., without building an intermediate list):

```py
>>>  sum(row[0] * b for row, b in zip(A, B, strict=True))
210
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be repeated solution, however:

```
>>> u = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
>>> v = [3, 7]
```

In plain `Python`:

```
>>> sum([x*y for (x, *x2), y in zip(u,v)])
31
```

Or using `numpy` (as described in [user57368](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919541/2839786)'s answer) :

```
import numpy as np
>>> np.dot(np.array(u)[:,0], v)
31
```

Answer (score 0):

All above answers are correct, but in my opinion the most pythonic way to calculate dot product is:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=[4,5,6]
>>> sum(map(lambda pair:pair[0]*pair[1],zip(a,b)))
32
```