# Multiplying Lists through Functions

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

I have two functions (`price()` and `sold()`) that create a random list of numbers. The third function (`itemSale()`) is suppose to multiply the lists from `price()` and `sold()` together, create a new list based off of the answers, then display them. Here is my code:

```
def main():
    itemSale()

def price():
    priceList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for i in range (10):
        priceList[i] = random.uniform(1.0,1000.0)
        print("${:7.2f}".format(priceList[i]))
    return priceList[i]

def sold():
    itemsSold = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    for i in range (10):
        itemsSold[i] = random.randint(0,200)
        print ('%i' %(itemsSold[i]))
    return itemsSold[i]

def itemSale():
    itemSale = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    totSale = sold()*price()
    print("${:7.2f}".format(totSale))
```

It will display the random generated numbers in the first two functions, but will only multiply the last number from those lists together and I can't figure out how to get it to work properly.

```
#from sold()
146
119
52
117
200
30
74
23
151
161
#from price()
$ 308.23
$ 116.05
$ 531.93
$ 730.77
$ 917.83
$ 949.44
$ 750.43
$ 427.39
$ 125.91
$  14.06
#from itemSale()
$2262.96
```

Comment: You are saying its doing `161 * 14.06`? Perhaps, I think you might be looking at cartesian product of the two lists, is that what you want?

Comment: See [What is the pythonic way to calculate dot product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919530/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-calculate-dot-product)

Answer (score 2):

Each function is returning the last item only, why not return the entire list? e.g change

```
return priceList[i]
```

to

```
return priceList
```

You then need to multiply each pairwise item in the list

```
totSale = sold()*price()
```

becomes

```
totSale = sum([x*y for x,y in zip(sold(),price())])
```

Comment: `sum(imap(mul, sold(), price()))`

Comment: `totSale = sum([x*y for x,y in zip(sold(),price())])` sums up everything doesn't it? I was trying to get each value in each index to multiply the other lists index values. So `x=[1,2,3,4]` `*` `y=[2,3,4,5]` giving me `xy=[2,6,12,20]`

Comment: Just remove the sum(...)

Comment: Lol wow, I feel stupid. I tried that and it was giving me a `TypeError` but I didn't realize it was in my `print` statement, just assumed it was in the `totSale` equation. Thank you for the help!