# Is there really an @ operator in Python to calculate dot product?

Tags: python, operators

Is this answer correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662710/1175080 ?

Quoting that answer.

> In Python 3.5, there is a new operator for the dot product,  so you
>   can write a= A @ B  instead of a= numpy.dot(A,B)

It does not seem to work for me.

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:40:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> a @ b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'list' and 'list'
>>>
```

But the linked answer has received 6 upvotes, so I must be missing something. Can you provide a complete example that shows how to use the `@` operator to calculate a dot product?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See [what's new in Python 3.5, section matrix mult (PEP 465)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-465-a-dedicated-infix-operator-for-matrix-multiplication):

> PEP 465 adds the `@` infix operator for matrix multiplication. **Currently, no builtin Python types implement the new operator**, however, it can be implemented by defining `__matmul__()`, `__rmatmul__()`, and `__imatmul__()` for regular, reflected, and in-place matrix multiplication. The semantics of these methods is similar to that of methods defining other infix arithmetic operators.

So, you would have to implement those methods yourself.

Or, use `numpy>=1.10` which already has support for the new operator:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.ones(3)
>>> m = numpy.eye(3)
>>> x @ m
array([ 1., 1., 1.])
```