# dot product within a nested list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, dot-product

I would like to ask whether it is possible to create a dot product within this nested list a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2],[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]  in Python without using numpy

I tried:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[2,4,2],[1,2,3], [5,6,7]]

for x, y in zip(a):
    temp = []
    for m, n in zip(x):
        temp.append(m * n)
    c.append([sum(temp)])

print(c)
```

However I got an error message:

> not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the pythonic way to calculate dot product?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919530/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-calculate-dot-product)

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack and zip `a`, then use `operator` and `reduce` (built-in in Python 2.x):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from operator import mul
>>> sum(reduce(mul, i) for i in zip(*a))
232
```

In other words:

```
>>> i, j, k = zip(*a)

>>> i
(1, 2, 1, 5)
>>> j
(2, 4, 2, 6)
>>> k
(3, 2, 3, 7)
```

Then you take `sum( (1*2*1*5, 2*4*2*6, 3*2*3*7) )`.